# Highlight the firedate in FSCalendar in objective c

Tags: ios, calendar, uilocalnotification

Problem: I want to highlight the fired date in my calendar, I used `FSCalendar` and `RSDayFlow` Calendar but cannot achieve this by using these Calendars.

Comment: What do you mean by the fired date?

Comment: That means selected date

Comment: But that is swift only,i used objective c

Comment: Damn. I didnt realize you require objectiveC. My Bad then. I guess you can file an issue on Github for FSCalendar. Its creator will respond to you